# Como testar um app criado na unity para Android num emulador com logcat como no Android Studio?

Tags: android, unity3d, unity-5

Na `unity` desenvolvendo para Android, ele não testa exatamente como num emulador como `Android Studio`. Eu sei que dá para gerar um `apk` e testar no aparelho físico, mas eu queria testar num emulador ou até mesmo no aparelho físico com `logcat` igual do `Android Studio`. Será tem algum jeito ?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, exite uma maneira.

É uma aplicação chamada [**UnityRemote 4**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html), neste link pode encontrar todas as informações de como configurar, pode fazê-lo sem gerar a APK, caso queira utiliza-lo num aparelho físico ou num emulador, caso queira utilizar num emulador, basta instalar essa App e configura-la como está no **Docs** da **Unity3d**.

Resumidamente os passos que terão de ser dados para a utilização correcta do **UnityRemote 4** são:

1. Instalar o a App UnityRemote4;
2. Ligar o dispositivo móvel ao computador por USB (caso seja um emulador, ignore este passo);
3. Colocar o dispositivo móvel em modo programador;
4. Entrar no Unity3d e abrir o projecto desejado;
5. Ir a Edit > Project Settings > Editor;
6. Escolher Device a opção de Any Android Device ou Any iOS Device (dependendo do dispositivo móvel desejado).

As outras opções dentro do Editor Settings, não são relevantes mas eu recomendo o uso tal como está nesta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Download da App para Android:** [**Clique Aqui**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unity3d.genericremote&hl=pt_PT).

**Download da App para iOS: [Clique Aqui](https://itunes.apple.com/pt/app/unity-remote-4/id871767552?mt=8)**